# Working on web based database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have coded a desktop application that uses sql server compact database with Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition. The databases are in the same folder with the application. Ive made that application 5 years ago, and now i want to make it to work online. Is there a way to work online? I mean the databases are stored an internet site and my application get data and write data to the databases that are on internet. So every user may see the data wherever they are. Sorry for my weak language and programming knowledge.

Comment: yes. You _could_ put the database online directly (e.g. in Azure) or something and open the port to it and make your desktop app connect to it (simply change your connection string, I think), but this can have security risks, you'd have to be very careful. A more modern and secure approach would be to do that, but not open to the internet, and instead place a REST API online in front of it. Either way I think you should migrate from SQL Compact to full SQL, if you plan to host in the cloud and have quite a few users. See. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592944(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Obviously if you go down the REST API approach you'd need more of a re-write of the original app to call URLs via HTTP instead of making direct DB calls (instead the API handles the database comms and the business logic, and the app is more of a dumb client). You might also consider ditching the app entirely and re-writing as a web-based application using ASP.NET. Microsoft actually has some useful documentation on potential application architectures here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/architecture

Comment: Thanks alot for your helps and advise.. i will work on it.